lstlisting and newcommand option
Using the lstlisting package I was able to color code my text background and also bold the commands using the \lstset{escapeinside={(*}{*)}} function. However, I would like substitute a new command in place of (*\bfseries <command>*).
How difficult would it be to use the \renewcommand{} to replace (*\bfseries <command>*) with something like \textbc{}. I am very uncertain about the syntax. Any help is appreciated.
I am helping some content developers migrate to LaTeX from Markdown and anything i can do to make the transition easier, e.g., using simple LaTeX markup, would help much.
Here is my MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings} % listing package with lstset function
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{helvet} % sets the font type as helvetica
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{couriers} % use Courier New font for computer code
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{codeblock}{RGB}{255,252,246} % light beige, code background
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}% use Helvetica as the default font
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % ensure there is no indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt} % 1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

\lstset{%
    language=,
    escapeinside={(*}{*)},
    tabsize=2,
    basicstyle=\small,
    stringstyle=\textbf,
    xleftmargin=0pt,
    xrightmargin=0pt,
    backgroundcolor=\color{codeblock},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true, % force lines to break so they do not extend past margins
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    columns=fullflexible
}%

\begin{document}

This is plain text using the Helvetica font.

\begin{lstlisting}
This is (*\bfseries bolded computer text*) using serif text.
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
ex1 (ttyu0)

login: (*\bfseries lab*)
Password:

--- JUNOS 24.4R1.12 built 2024-10-17 14:37:30 UTC
{master:0}
lab@ex1> (*\bfseries configure*) <!-- this command is bold -->
Entering configuration mode

{master:0}[edit]
lab@ex1# (*\bfseries load override sample.config*) <!-- this command is bold -->
load complete

{master:0}[edit]
lab@ex1# commit  <!-- bold this command -->
configuration check succeeds
commit complete

{master:0}[edit]
lab@ex1# edit interfaces  <!-- bold this command -->

{master:0}[edit interfaces]
lab@ex1# copy ae0 to ge-0/0/3 <!-- bold this command -->

{master:0}[edit interfaces]
lab@ex1# show ge-0/0/3  <!-- bold this command -->
unit 0 {
    family ethernet-switching {
        interface-mode trunk;
        vlan {
            members all;
        }
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


well, if you are using that code for escape, then you have to use that code for escape in order to escape. so you could use, say, {* \textbc{bold command}*} (but why? why not \textbf{bold command}?), but \textbc{bold command} will be treated verbatim because that's what you've told latex to do. if your code doesn't actually include backslashes, you could use a different approach. does the code include them? you need some markup for escape which doesn't conflict with what you want treated verbatim.

have you considered just teaching them to convert markdown to latex? the other way is lossy, but markdown to latex I would think could be fine.

why do you have both \usepackage{helvet} and \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}? you should use parskip rather than setting indent/skip manually. also, you don't need inputenc unless your install is ancient (i.e. decades rather than years).

Thanks for the suggestions about removing the {\sfdefault}{phv} and the \parskip commands, but those were not part of my question. Your first response was a bit confusing. I will go ahead and try some other escape characters to escape the \textbf{{}.

I figured it out. It was using the moredelim option within lstset.
I replaced the following lines in my lstset preamble:
\lstset{%
    language=,
    moredelim=[is][\bfseries]{(*}{*)}, % added this line
    %escapeinside={[*}{*)},            % escaped this line 
    tabsize=2,
    basicstyle=\small,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\textbf,
    xleftmargin=0pt,
    xrightmargin=0pt,
    backgroundcolor=\color{codeblock},
    breaklines=true, % force lines to break so they do not extend past margins
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    columns=fullflexible
}%

Then, I simply added the open parens and asterisk and then the close parens and asterisk around the bold command.
\begin{lstlisting}
    This is (*bolded computer text*) using serif text.
\end{lstlisting}

I could just as easily have added an ampersand (@) or square brackets. I just needed to esacpe some characters that do not normally occur within JSON code.
@cfr thanks for the pointers.
